# NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED - only for few clients not all - CentOS Server

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, certificate

Salam,
I installed *.domain.com SSL Certificate in a CentOS 7.1 (apache2) Server, it was Ok first but now some of our client having problem with it,
I tried Server Update.
I tried Cache clear in clients Browsers
I tried different browsers
and I check the date and time.

and I actually do not know it's from the server or its from client side.

Error:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from subdomain.domain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED
  Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google. Privacy policy
ReloadHide advanced
subdomain.domain.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Chrome tried to connect to  subdomain.domain.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. Either an attacker is trying to pretend to be support.shamal.net, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit support.shamal.net right now because this certificate has been revoked. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

Comment: Check with the issuer of your certificate if it's still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate had been revoked. This can be seen here:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=support.shamal.net
This is a problem with the cert configured on the server. You'd need to ask GoDaddy why this happened - could be you asked to get it reissued, could be they think your untrustworthy for sone reason.

So in theory EVERY client should get a message like that above. But there are some subtleties, which might explain why this is not the case:

If the browser was unable to contact the CA which issued the cert then it will assume he best and assume it's not revoked (so called "soft fail").

Unlike other browsers, Chrome does not do real time checks as whether a cert is revoked by default (as they think it is slow and doesn't add that much protection because of reasons like "soft fail" - a contentious opinion). Instead they rely on a concept call CRLSets which are downloaded periodically by Chrome. This contains a list of revoked certificates. So there is obviously a delay in getting into Chrome and there is some question as to how complete CRLSets are. So this might explain why some Chrome clients are rejecting this and some not. Are the ones that reject it newer version perhaps?

Lastly some tools (particularly Antivirus like Avast or Corporate proxy tools) deliberately replace the cert with one of their own so they can still read the traffic to scan for viruses or for other reasons. Of course they shouldn't do this if a cert is revoked like in this case but stranger things have happened. Double click the green padlock to view the certificate and its chain to see if it was issued by a someone other than GoDaddy.

Comment: Yes thank, it's been revoked, because we used different csr for different serve and platform, the ssl is for *.domain.com